# Migrations Different Assembly

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following structure.

- MyOrg.Api (AspNet Core Web App)
- MoOrg.DataAccess (Containing the DbContext)

I want the Migrations live in the DataAccess Assembly. 
Ive tried almost every combination of configuration but cant get it work probably.

#### MyOrg.Api (Startup.cs)

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // default stuff.. 
        services.AddDbContext<MyOrg.DataAccess.MyDatabaseContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlite("Filename=./myDbContext.db", b => b.MigrationsAssembly("MyOrg.DataAccess"));
        });
    }
```

#### MyOrg.DataAccess

```
    public class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Something> Somethings { get; set; }

        public MyDatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<MyDatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
```

How to do it right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705694/add-migration-with-diferent-assembly

Comment: Thanks but thats not the answer i was looking for. In that answer the migrations lives in the project and not in the data access assembly.

Comment: Check again. I'm pretty sure this is basically the same scenario.

Comment: Option 1. in the other answer is basically what i want. BUT the problem is that "Update-Database" creates the database file in the bin directory of the data access assembly. When i run my app it looks for the myDbContext.db in the bin directory of the api project.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That would be good to add to the question.

Answer (score 4):

In your **MyOrg.DataAccess**, create a new class MigrationDbContext deriving from MyDatabaseContext with and OnConfiguring method override :

```
public class MigrationDbContext: MyDatabaseContext
{
    public MigrationDbContext()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlite("Filename=./myDbContext.db");
        base.OnConfiguring(options);
    }
}
```

Since **.Net Core 2.1** you don't need to add a reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`, `dotnet ef` is a global tool.
If you use **.Net Core 2.0** or above, add the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` as a *DotNetCliToolReference* to your **MyOrg.DataAccess** project :

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
     <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet"
                            Version="1.1.6" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then go to your MyOrg.DataAccess project directory using a command prompt and run :
`dotnet ef --startup-project ../MyOrg.Api/ migrations add Initial -c MigationDbContext`
to create an initial migration named **Initial** (I assume ../MyOrg.Api/ is the relative path to your startup project)

To update your database run:
`dotnet ef --startup-project ../MyOrg.Api/ database update`

For more information read the doc [Entity Framework Core tools reference - .NET CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it working as follows (whilst also adhering to Onion Architecture):

1. Create a class library 'App.Core'

   - Add a 'Country' domain model to this library:

     ```
     public class Country
     {
         public int Id { get; set; }

         public string Name { get; set; }
     }
     ```
   - This is just a simple class to get things working quickly
2. Create a class library 'App.Infrastructure'

   - Add a DbContext to this library:

     ```
     public class AppDbContext : DbContext
     {
         public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

         protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
         {
             optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost;Database=App;Trusted_Connection=True;",
             x => x.MigrationsAssembly("App.Migrations"));
         }
     }
     ```
   - 'App.Migrations' will be our separate class library just for migrations
   - 'App.Infrastructure' needs to reference 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' and 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools'
3. Run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`

   - Do this from the command line in the 'App.Infrastructure' directory
   - This will create a 'Migrations' folder in your 'App.Infrastructure' class library with a migration called 'InitialCreate'
4. Create a class library 'App.Migrations'

   - Move the 'Migrations' folder from 'App.Infrastructure' to 'App.Migrations' - you will need to update the namespaces after the move
   - Add a project reference in 'App.Migrations' to 'App.Infrastructure'
   - Edit the .csproj file for 'App.Migrations' and add an output path:

   netcoreapp2.1
       App.Infrastructure\bin\$(Configuration)\

   - The above path will be correct if 'App.Infrastructure' and 'App.Migrations' are in the same directory, if not, the output path will need to be adjusted
   - On build this results in 'App.Migrations' being output to the 'App.Infrastructure' bin directory - we need to do this as we can't reference 'App.Migrations' in 'App.Infrastructure' as this results in a circular reference, so this is a workaround
5. Build the solution
6. Run `dotnet ef database update` from the command line in the 'App.Infrastructure' directory and this should create the database and create the 'Countries' table
7. Run `dotnet ef migrations add AddCity --project App.Migrations` for your next migration

   - 'AddCity' is just another migration to create a 'Cities' table - this requires adding a 'City' class and updating the DbContext
   - Run the command from the 'App.Infrastructure' directory and the migration will be added to the 'App.Migrations' class library
8. Remember to rebuild the solution every time a migration is added