# Change IdentityServer4 Entity Framework table names

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

I am trying to change the default table names created by the PersistedGrantDb and ConfigurationDb for IdentityServer4 and have Entity Framework generate the correct SQL. For example; instead of the using the entity `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.ApiResource` using the table `ApiResources`, I want the data to be mapped into a table named `mytesttable`

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables) this should be as simple as adding `ToTable` invocations for each entity that I want to remap in the `DBContext's` `OnModelCreating` method to override the default behaviour of TableName = EntityName. The problem is that this does indeed create a table `mytesttable` but the SQL created by Entity Framework at runtime still uses `ApiResources` in the query and consequently fails.

The steps I've taken are I've created a `DBContext` that derives from IdentityServer's `ConfigurationDbContext` in order to be able to override `OnModelCreating` and customize the table names:

```
public class MyTestDbContext : ConfigurationDbContext
{
    public MyTestDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions) : base(options, storeOptions)
    { }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("OnModelCreating invoking...");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.ApiResource>().ToTable("mytesttable");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        Console.WriteLine("...OnModelCreating invoked");
    }
}
```

I've also implemented a `DesignTimeDbContextFactoryBase<MyTestDBContext>` class to manufacture the `MyTestDbContext` instance when invoked at design time via the `dotnet ef migrations` command line syntax.

This works and an invocation of `dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerConfigurationDbMigration -c MyTestDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/MyTestContext` creates the initial migrations in my assembly.

I then start the IdentityServer instance, invoking a test method from `Startup` that contains the following logic:

```
private static void InitalizeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
         {

            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyTestDbContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();

            /* Add some test data here... */
        }
}
```

and this happily wanders through and creates the necessary tables in my PostGRES database using `NpgSQL` provider, including the table named `mytesttable` in place of `ApiResources` for the entity `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.ApiResource`. However, when I invoke a command from the IdentityServer instance, the SQL that is generated is still referencing `ApiResources` instead of `mytesttable`:

```
  Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT x."Id", x."Description", x."DisplayName", x."Enabled", x."Name"
  FROM "ApiResources" AS x
  ORDER BY x."Id"
  Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "ApiResources" does not exist
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Ok - so it turns out you can alter the table names that the entities target in the `AddConfigurationStore` and `AddOperationalStore` configuration methods exposed on the object returned by `AddIdentityServer` in `Startup`. So; `services.AddIdentityServer().AddConfigurationStore(options => { options.ApiResource.Name = "mytesttable"; })` - All the IdentityServer entity -> tablename mappings are exposed in this manner. Also add the necessary `ToTable()` call in the DBContexts `OnModelCreating` and everything works perfectly with tables named differently to the entities they underpin.

Comment: Funny, I'm solving the exact same problem today.  You should add this as an answer and accept.

Comment: I've written a more comprehensive answer and posted it below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is two parts to this answer; firstly the table names need to be adjusted in IdentityServer's configuration so that it generates queries using the new table names. Secondly; the schema generated by entity framework needs to be amended so that it knows to create the differently named tables for the Identity Framework entities. Read on...

So, first up; the ability to change the table names used in the Entity Framework queries is exposed on `AddOperationalStore` and `AddConfigurationStore` methods that hang off the `AddIdentityServer` middleware method. The `options` argument of the delegate supplied to the configuration methods exposes the table names, for example: `options.{EntityName}.Name = {WhateverTableNameYouWantToUse}` - or `options.ApiResource.Name = mytesttable`. You can also override the schema on a per table basis as well by adjusting the `Schema` property.

The example below uses reflection to update all the entities to use table names prefixed with `idn_`, so `idn_ApiResources`, `idn_ApiScopes` etc:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddConfigurationStore(options => {
                // Loop through and rename each table to 'idn_{tablename}' - E.g. `idn_ApiResources`
                foreach(var p in options.GetType().GetProperties()) {
                if (p.PropertyType == typeof(IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Options.TableConfiguration))
                {
                    object o = p.GetGetMethod().Invoke(options, null);
                    PropertyInfo q = o.GetType().GetProperty("Name");

                    string tableName = q.GetMethod.Invoke(o, null) as string;
                    o.GetType().GetProperty("Name").SetMethod.Invoke(o, new object[] { $"idn_{tableName}" });
                    
                }
            }

         // Configure DB Context connection string and migrations assembly where migrations are stored  
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseNpgsql(_configuration.GetConnectionString("IDPDataDBConnectionString"),
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(IdentityServer.Data.DbContexts.MyTestDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));
}
.AddOperationalStore(options => { 

 // Copy and paste from AddConfigurationStore logic above.
}
```

The second part is to amend the schema generated by entity framework from the IdentityServer entities. To accomplish this you've got two choices; you can either derive from one of IdentityServer's supplied DBContexts; `ConfigurationDbContext` or `PeristedGrantDbContext` and then override the `OnModelCreating` method to remap each IdentityServer entity to the modified table name and then create your initial migration or updated migration as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables) (Fluent Api syntax), **or** you can create the initial migration from the supplied IdentityServer DBContext's `ConfigurationDbContext` and `PersistedGrantDbContext` as per the tutorial [Adding Migrations](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html) section, and then just do a find and replace with a text editor on all the table names and references to those table names in the created migration files.

Whichever method you choose you will still need to use the `dotnet ef migrations ...` command line syntax to create either the initial migration files as shown in [Adding Migrations](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html) or a modified set with table changes and once you've done this, run your IdentityServer project and the schema will be created in the target database.

Note; `OnModelCreating` is invoked via the `dotnet ef migrations` syntax (aka at Design Time) and also at runtime if you call `Database.Migrate()` on your DBContext - E.g. `MyDbContextInstance.Database.Migrate()` (or the async equivalent method).

If you want to use a custom DBContext so you can customise `OnModelCreating`, you need to add a few design time classes which are used when you call `dotnet ef` from the command line and add the new context to `Startup`.

For the sake of completeness below is a hacky rough example where the context target is a PostGres database (use `UseSQLServer` in place of `UseNpgsql` or whatever your backing store is if it differs) and the connection string name is `IDPDataDBConnectionString` in the appsettings.json file and the custom DB context in this case is `MyTestDbContext` which derives from IdentityServer's `ConfigurationDbContext`.

Copy and paste the code, adjust the path to `appsettings.json` (or refactor) and then from the command line execute `dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerConfigurationDbMigration -c MyTestDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/ConfigurationDbCreatedWithMyTestContext` and you should see the Entity Framework generate the schema migration files using whatever overrides you've placed in `OnModelCreating` on your derived context. The example below also includes some `Console.WriteLine` invocations to make it easier to track what's going on.

Add this to `Startup`:

```
 services.AddDbContext<MyTestDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseNpgsql(_configuration.GetConnectionString("IDPDataDBConnectionString"));
        });
```

**Note** the use of the design time classes also allows you to separate your IdentityServer database migration files into a separate class library if you like. Make sure you target it in `Startup` if you do this (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705694/add-migration-with-different-assembly) for more info).

```
namespace MyIdentityServer.DataClassLibrary.DbContexts
{

public class MyTestDbContext : ConfigurationDbContext
{
    public MyTestDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions) : base(options, storeOptions)
    { }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("OnModelCreating invoking...");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Map the entities to different tables here
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities.ApiResource>().ToTable("mytesttable");

        Console.WriteLine("...OnModelCreating invoked");
    }

}
public class MyTestContextDesignTimeFactory : DesignTimeDbContextFactoryBase<MyTestDbContext>
{

    public MyTestContextDesignTimeFactory()
        : base("IDPDataDBConnectionString", typeof(MyTestContextDesignTimeFactory).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name)
    {
    }

    protected override MyTestDbContext CreateNewInstance(DbContextOptions<MyTestDbContext> options)
    {
        var x = new DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext>();

        Console.WriteLine("Here we go...");

        var optionsBuilder = newDbContextOptionsBuilder<ConfigurationDbContext>();

        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("IDPDataDBConnectionString", postGresOptions => postGresOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(MyTestContextDesignTimeFactory).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));

        DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> ops = optionsBuilder.Options;

        return new MyTestDbContext(ops, new ConfigurationStoreOptions());
    }
}




/* Enable these if you just want to host your data migrations in a separate assembly and use the IdentityServer supplied DbContexts 

public class ConfigurationContextDesignTimeFactory : DesignTimeDbContextFactoryBase<ConfigurationDbContext>
{

    public ConfigurationContextDesignTimeFactory()
        : base("IDPDataDBConnectionString", typeof(ConfigurationContextDesignTimeFactory).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name)
    {
    }

    protected override ConfigurationDbContext CreateNewInstance(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options)
    {
        return new ConfigurationDbContext(options, new ConfigurationStoreOptions());
    }
}

public class PersistedGrantContextDesignTimeFactory : DesignTimeDbContextFactoryBase<PersistedGrantDbContext>
{
    public PersistedGrantContextDesignTimeFactory()
        : base("IDPDataDBConnectionString", typeof(PersistedGrantContextDesignTimeFactory).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name)
    {
    }

    protected override PersistedGrantDbContext CreateNewInstance(DbContextOptions<PersistedGrantDbContext> options)
    {
        return new PersistedGrantDbContext(options, new OperationalStoreOptions());
    }
}
*/

public abstract class DesignTimeDbContextFactoryBase<TContext> :
IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
    protected string ConnectionStringName { get; }
    protected String MigrationsAssemblyName { get; }
    public DesignTimeDbContextFactoryBase(string connectionStringName, string migrationsAssemblyName)
    {
        ConnectionStringName = connectionStringName;
        MigrationsAssemblyName = migrationsAssemblyName;
    }

    public TContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        return Create(
            Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"),
            ConnectionStringName, MigrationsAssemblyName);
    }
    protected abstract TContext CreateNewInstance(
        DbContextOptions<TContext> options);

    public TContext CreateWithConnectionStringName(string connectionStringName, string migrationsAssemblyName)
    {
        var environmentName =
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        var basePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

        return Create(basePath, environmentName, connectionStringName, migrationsAssemblyName);
    }

    private TContext Create(string basePath, string environmentName, string connectionStringName, string migrationsAssemblyName)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(basePath)
            .AddJsonFile(@"c:\change\this\path\to\appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        var config = builder.Build();

        var connstr = config.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connstr) == true)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Could not find a connection string named 'default'.");
        }
        else
        {
            return CreateWithConnectionString(connstr, migrationsAssemblyName);
        }
    }

    private TContext CreateWithConnectionString(string connectionString, string migrationsAssemblyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            throw new ArgumentException(
         $"{nameof(connectionString)} is null or empty.",
         nameof(connectionString));

        var optionsBuilder =
             new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>();

        Console.WriteLine(
            "MyDesignTimeDbContextFactory.Create(string): Connection string: {0}",
            connectionString);

        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connectionString, postGresOptions => postGresOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssemblyName));

        DbContextOptions<TContext> options = optionsBuilder.Options;

        Console.WriteLine("Instancing....");

        return CreateNewInstance(options);
    }
}

}
```

Side note; If you've already got a database with the IdentityServer tables in, you can just rename them manually ignoring Entity Framework migrations - the only bit you'll then need is the changes in `Startup` to `AddConfigurationStore` and `AddOperationalStore`.

Comment: How does [this new nuget package](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.NamingConventions) change things with IdentityServer4? Can you do an updated answer please?