# How to create migration when DBContext in different assembly

Tags: msbuild, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have `NET Core 3.1` application where my `[models,dbcontext,application]` are all in their own assemblies.I am trying to issue a migration(s) for the  application.I keep getting this error:

```
$ dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project DataAccess
```

> MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. Switch:
>   DataAccess Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an
>   MSBuild-based .NET Core project. If you're using custom
>   BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use
>   the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.

**Current Structure**

```
*root
  -App  (.NET Core 3.1)
  -DataAccess  (.NET Standard 2.1)   (Contains the DBContext)
  -Models     (.NET Standard 2.1)   (contains models)
```

I have also tried creating a separate assembly for migrations and use the MigrationAssembly extension in my `App` :

```
services.AddDbContext<[some DBContext]>(x => x.UseSqlServer([some string],x=>x.MigrationsAssembly("Migrations")));
```

**Tried Structure**

```
 *root
      -App
      -Migrations (.NET Standard 2.1)
      -DataAccess (.NET Standard 2.1)
      -Models (.NET Standard 2.1)
```

I do not understand how this should be done.I want to be able to do migrations and ideally i would like to keep them in their own assembly.Currently i can't do them at all.

**P.S**
 I have also tried adding this to my `App` csproj file:

```
<GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>True</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
```

Comment: In same project structure below command works for me. CLI opens in App folder

App> dotnet ef migrations add your_migrationName  --project "Absolute path to your migration assembly (c:/root/migrations)"

Comment: Answer is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705694/add-migration-with-different-assembly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add migration with different assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705694/add-migration-with-different-assembly)

Answer (score 7):

the answer given by @Ajay above finally worked for me, after days and days googling for it:

to insert the migrations assembly complete path in the --project argument, like this:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Mymigration --project "c:\repos\myproject\Data"
```

...and you should execute this command from your main startup project (like c:\repos\myproject\Web)

Answer (score 5):

exactly same issue here, since hours, good to know not being the only one getting crazy about!

Finally worked it out:
I'm using EFCore.Tools in Package Manager Console instead of dotnet Cli:

//Add Migration

```
Add-Migration *name* -Project *Library project* -StartupProject *StartUp/Web project*
```

//Update Database

```
Update-Database -Project *Library project* -StartupProject *StartUp/Web project* -verbose
```

i would go this direction... have fun!

Answer (score 1):

First change directory to project directory, then add .csproj

```
$ dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project DataAccess.csproj
```

I hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

I used the full Directory path and it's worked. And also we should use correct project references.

ex: `dotnet ef migrations add Initial --project D:\NK-Pro\API\TaskAPI.DataAccess\TaskAPI.DataAccess.csproj`