# Unable to create migrations. Error MSB1009: Project file does not exist

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, dotnet-cli

I started to develop Asp.net Core web API with the VS code. But when I try to create ef migrations I get this error:

```
PS D:\PROJECTS\GrandExchange> dotnet ef --startup-project /API.csproj migrations add IdentityAdded --context Persistence --output-dir Migrations --project /Persistence/Persistence.csproj
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: D:\Persistence\Persistence.csproj
Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.
PS D:\PROJECTS\GrandExchange>
```

My folder structure looks like this: [Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x2yp.png)

So where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, found a solution elsewhere.
I just needed insert the migrations assembly complete path in the --project argument, like this:

```
PS D:\PROJECTS\GrandExchange\api> dotnet ef migrations add IdentityAdded --context DataContext --output-dir Migrations --project "D:\PROJECTS\GrandExchange\Persistence\Persistence.csproj"
```

and executed this command from my main startup project (like D:\PROJECTS\GrandExchange\API)

This solution I found there:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63508741/12959213

Answer (score 1):

To add a new migration, run the below command in a terminal:

```
dotnet ef migrations add <MIGRATION_NAME> --project <PROJECT> --startup-project <STARTUP_PROJECT>
```