Moving database contexts to library project results in "FileNotFound" exception
I have a .NET Core 7 solution EIT which had only 1 project: EIT. This project uses Entity Framework Core to model and access the database. This worked fine.
Now I want to add several Windows services which are supposed to run independently of the web application. Since they also all need to access the database, I thought it would be a good idea to move all models and database code to a separate project that all other projects can depend on.
This way, small Windows Service projects don't have to depend on the much bigger web application project to access the database.
Resulting solution EIT:

DataLibrary (class library project, database access and models)
EIT (web app project)
MarketHistoryDataService (Windows service project, accesses an external API and the database to process market data)

All projects target .NET 7.0 with C# 11.0.
Project EIT has a reference to the project DataLibrary. And all models and files related to database management have been moved to this project.
After battling an error that has been solved by adding
public ApplicationDbContext() { } 

to my ApplicationDbContext, I now run into

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
'EIT.DataLibrary, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'EIT.DataLibrary, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Again I am very confused since I do not understand what the issue is. Project EIT has a reference to project DataLibrary and on the published application file path in IIS I can find:
- DataLibrary.deps.json
- DataLibrary.dll
- DataLibrary.pdb
- DataLibrary.runtimeconfig.json

in the main directory of the website, alongside EIT.exe, EIT.dll, and all other nuget package files.
Nuget packages added to DataLibrary project are:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Dignostics.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Newtonsoft.Json
Serilog

I read on the internet that the EF Core packages are required, so I added them. Of course the other projects have these packages as well.
Although this solution uses 2 database contexts, let's focus on the main one: ApplicationDbContext, since this is indirectly referenced in the error:

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Could not load file or assembly 'EIT.DataLibrary, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.)
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'EIT.DataLibrary, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'EIT.DataLibrary, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'EIT.DataLibrary, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'EIT.DataLibrary, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyName, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext, RuntimeAssembly requestingAssembly, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsAssembly..ctor(ICurrentDbContext currentContext, IDbContextOptions options, IMigrationsIdGenerator idGenerator, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetRelationalService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 databaseFacade)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.MigrateAsync(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at DataLibrary.Data.DatabaseInitializer.MigrateAsync() in D:\prog\visual studio\EIT\EIT\DataLibrary\Data\DbInitializer.cs:line 40
   at DataLibrary.Data.DatabaseInitializer.SeedAsync() in D:\prog\visual studio\EIT\EIT\DataLibrary\Data\DbInitializer.cs:line 31

For reference: DbInitializer is supposed to seed the database with data if it is empty, but also triggers EF Core migrations to run:
virtual public async Task SeedAsync()
{
    // Apply EF Core migration scripts
    await MigrateAsync();

    // Seed EIT data
    // await SeedEitAsync();
}

private async Task MigrateAsync()
{
    await _context.Database.MigrateAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

which is where the error arises.
The absurd thing is I can even move DbInitializer.cs  to DataLibrary project, it does get called and the error does not change.
How can a class in DataLibrary get called when DataLibrary.dll cannot be found?
Program.cs:
namespace BlazorApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Warning()
                .WriteTo.Debug(new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter())
                // File location should have write permission granted
                .WriteTo.File(@"C:\\EitLogs\\EitApplicationLog.txt",rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();
            
            CreateHostBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()  
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets(); });
        
    }
}

Startup.cs:
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using AdminLTE_Test2.Areas.Identity;
using DataLibrary.Data;
using EVEStandard;
using EVEStandard.Enumerations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Fluxor;


namespace DataLibrary.Data
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), x => x.MigrationsAssembly("EIT.DataLibrary")),
                
                    contextLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped, 
                    optionsLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
            
            services.AddDbContextFactory<SdeDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        Configuration.GetConnectionString("StaticDataExportDB"))); 
               
            services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))); 
            
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(e=> {
                e.DetailedErrors = true;
            });
            services
                .AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider,
                    RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
            
            // DB Creation and Seeding
            services.AddTransient<IDatabaseInitializer, DatabaseInitializer>();
            
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddAntDesign();

            services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();

            var currentAssembly = typeof(Startup).Assembly;
            services.AddFluxor(options => options.ScanAssemblies(currentAssembly).UseReduxDevTools());
            
            // Add cookie authentication and set the login url
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
                });
            
            // Initialize the client
            var esiClient = new EVEStandardAPI(
                "EVEStandard",                  // User agent
                DataSource.Tranquility,                 // Server [Tranquility/Singularity]
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));       // Timeout

            // Register EVEStandard SSO if you want to use it, you don't have to use EVEStandard SSO with EVEStandard.
            var sso = new SSOv2(DataSource.Tranquility, Configuration["SSOCallbackUrl"], Configuration["ClientId"], Configuration["SecretKey"]);
            services.AddSingleton<SSOv2>(sso);
            
            // Register with DI container
            services.AddSingleton<EVEStandardAPI>(esiClient);
            services.AddSingleton<SdeDataService>();
            services.AddSingleton<ApplicationDataService>();
            services.AddSingleton<EveEsiService>();
            services.AddSingleton<EveTycoonService>();
            services.AddSingleton<EveHistoricalMarketDataService>();
            
            // Session is required 
            services.AddSession();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var databaseInitializer = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IDatabaseInitializer>();
                databaseInitializer.SeedAsync().Wait();
            }
            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}

ApplicationDbContext:
using DataLibrary.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DataLibrary.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Character> Characters { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        
        public DbSet<CharacterBlueprint> CharacterBlueprints { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CharacterIndustryJob> CharacterIndustryJobs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CharacterMiningLedger> CharacterMiningLedgers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MarketItemPriceHistory> MarketItemPriceHistory { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MarketItemHistoryUpdateTimeStamp> MarketItemHistoryUpdateTimeStamps { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LastUpdateTimeStamp> LastUpdateTimeStamps { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MarketItemNotFound> MarketItemsNotFound { get; set; }
        
        public ApplicationDbContext() { }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.\\\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EIT;user id=xxx;password=xxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True");
        }
    }
}

Would anybody know how to fix this?
Update:
After Steve's hint with references I got a little confused with the Solution's name being EIT and the web app's name being the same. So I renamed the WebApp project to EITWeb
New Solution structure:
Solution name: EIT

DataLibrary (class library project, database access and models)
EITWeb (web app project)
MarketHistoryDataService (Windows service project, accesses an external API and the database to process market data)

The error now changed to:
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Could not load file or assembly 'EITWeb.DataLibrary, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.)
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'EITWeb.DataLibrary, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I think that DataLibrary.Data.DbInitializer is being called, so the reference from EitWeb to DatalLibrary is fine. However, DataLibrary.Data.DbInitializer calls
        private async Task MigrateAsync()
        {
            await _context.Database.MigrateAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

which then, for some reason,  tries to reference EITWeb.DataLibrary. This indeed, does not exist.
Would anyone know where I could be able to find/change/remove that reference?
My migrations were in Eit.Data (Now: EitWeb.Data) before I introduced DataLibrary. Does it have something to do with that? Now the migrations are in DataLibrary.Migrations and their namespace is namespace DataLibrary.Migrations

Probably need .UseSqlServer(..., options => options.MigrationsAssembly(...));. And adding the empty constructor is the wrong fix.

thanks Jeremy. As I am still an amateur I followed the instructions I found on the internet. You are correct of course. I removed the empty constructor. Thank you for the hint!

The error states that it is trying to find a DLL named "EIT.DataLibrary(.dll)" not "DataLibrary(.dll)" so I suspect something has possibly gotten mucked up with your project references.
The typical scenario I see issues like this popping up is when project references get disconnected and replaced with fixed path assembly references. Project references in Visual Studio are what you normally start out with which allows easy debugging and ensures changes to the supporting project built assemblies are automatically built and copied to EXEs and services. When these get fumbled, you end up with static references to a .DLL file in the /bin/Debug etc. folder. Basically at one point the project might have been named EIT.DataLibrary resulting in an EIT.DataLibrary.dll file existing and building, sitting in a debugging folder, then the project got renamed to "DataLibrary.dll" and the project reference got disconnected, leaving a reference to "EIT.DataLibrary.dll" that cannot be found at runtime.
Usually when something like this happens it involves investigations into the .csproj files for invalid references, followed by dropping references and re-adding them, doing a full clean and purge of the /obj and /bin folders, then a rebuild.
Start by opening your solution and going to the EIT web project and expanding "Dependencies" then going to "Projects". Find the reference to the "DataLibrary" and delete it. Then Right-click on the "Dependencies" and select "Add Project Reference" which should list the projects in your solution, and re-select the "DataLibrary" project. Do a "Clean Solution", then for safe measures search for /bin folders and /obj folders and delete those. Finally a "Rebuild All" to ensure you don't have any namespace resolution issues or other build problems, then check if your web project is now resolving the connection to the data library. Note that if you have other projects referencing the DataLibrary project you should do the same to be sure they have valid project references. This is especially important where you have Project A (web) -> Project C (DataLibrary) and Project A -> Project B (another library) -> Project C dependencies.
You can also check the settings for the default namespace and assembly name for your "DataLibrary" project to see if that has been altered. For .Net Core assemblies the assembly name typically defaults to "$(MSBuildProjectName)" while the default namespace defaults to "$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_"))". Someone may have replaced these with hard-coded strings.

Hi Steve, thanks for your feedback!!! Saddly It didnt change anything. I moved the DbInitializer to Datalibrary so it's in the same project as the DbContext and it is being called. the eerror however doesnt change (updated stacktrace above). It calls await MigrateAsync(); in DataLibrary and the complains the DLL cannot be found.
Csproj files all reference this:
<ItemGroup>       <ProjectReference Include="..\DataLibrary\DataLibrary.csproj" />     </ItemGroup>

Ugh,, migrations... I love to avoid 'em :) This might help get it solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705694/add-migration-with-different-assembly

I found the issue:
When I was moving the database contexts to `DataLibrary', I had to add the migration assembly for EF Core. For this, I added:
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), x => x.MigrationsAssembly("EIT.DataLibrary")),


Obviously, this is wrong and must be
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), x => x.MigrationsAssembly("DataLibrary")),

Thank you all for reading through my issue and thanks especially to Steve for taking the time to respond with such an extensive answer!
